# 'myStateType' was not declared in this scope caused by #typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scope, macros, typedef

I tried to use #typedef to declare a type as my own customized name for convenient use:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void dfs(vector<vector<char>>& board, int i, int j)
    {
        using namespace std;
        #typedef std::pair<int, int> myStateType;

        std::queue<myStateType> q; // error on this line
        ...
    }
};
```

However, compile error indicated on this line `std::queue<myStateType> q;`:

**'myStateType' was not declared in this scope**

I still haven't figure out how this error could have happened? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `#` part of the actual code? `typedef std::pair<int, int> myStateType;` should be fine.

Comment: I find it odd that you are using `using namespace std;` but also specify the `std::` namespace IIF the line appears after the `using` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef`  is a compiler token in the C and C++ programming languages, **not a MACRO**.

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> myStateType; // don't put # before
std:queue<myStateType> q;
```

**'myStateType' was not declared in this scope**: means that your programm is not aware of type: *myStateType*

Comment: I find calling [preprocessing directives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) macros a little misleading.

Comment: François Andrieux is right. By removing the '#', program works